# Clearcase command to check the existence of an element in a VOB

Tags: clearcase

What would be the command to check the existence of an element (say named "XYZ") in a Clearcase VOB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with [`cleartool describe`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm):

```
clertool describe yourView/yourVob/yourFile
```

But that implies that you have a view first.
I would recommend a dynamic view, as it is easier/quicker to set up and use (no update like in a snapshot view).

Comment: +1: ...with the caveat that the element might exist on other branches not visible using the current cspec...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that would leave you with one option... `cleartool find -all`, and that would take much longer than the simple `ct descr`.

Comment: Absolutely...and for most people, that is unlikely to be a real problem, but funnier things have been known.  Files do become obsolete and get removed from current branches.  A lot depends on the problem to be resolved.